# How to allocate memory in struct for char* fields

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

How to allocate memory for my `char *` fields in struct ?

My struct:

```
   struct student{
    int score;
    char* name;
    char* surname;
};
int main(){
    struct student st[];
    int i;
    int n = 5;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Score: \n");
        scanf("%d", &st[i].score);
        printf("Name \n");
        scanf("%s", &st[i].name);
        printf("Surname \n");
        scanf("%s",&st[i].surname)
    }

}
```

How to malloc to `char* name` and `char* surname` ? 

I must have an array of struct in form `struct student st[]`.

I don't know, how do this rationally.

```
void initialise_student( struct student *st, char* name, char* surname)
    {
     st->name = ( strlen( name ) + 1);
     st->surname = (strlen( surname ) +1 );
    }
    int main(){
     int i;
     int n = 5;
     struct student *st[n] = initialise_student();
     for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
       printf("Score: \n");
       scanf("%d", &st[i].score);
       printf("Name \n");
       scanf("%s", &st[i].name);
       printf("Surname \n");
       scanf("%s",&st[i].surname);
      }
```

How to match this ?

Comment: Where do the strings come from?

Comment: Strings come from keyboard by scanf

Comment: How do you want to alloc space for an unknown length of the string ?

Comment: `struct student st[];` : First of all, the size of the array is required.

Comment: @MarekPiszczaniuk sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Tell us a bit more of what you are __actually__ trying to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelWalz my program has to sort students by score. I know that do this with only  char arrays way, but I need it in form which I give up. Sorry for my English

Comment: You hardly want to `malloc` a pointer`, but an object it shall **point to**. Mind the details!

Comment: @MarekPiszczaniuk I can not understand what you are saying. If five records are needed, like `struct student st[5];`.

Comment: Please add the code details in code of your question for readability.

Comment: _I must have an array of struct in form struct student st[]_ This can't be done in C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `struct student st[]` with `char*` inside can't be done in C? I'm need use  pointer to `char*` inside struct , so this is possible. Maybe I'm thinking bad?

Comment: @MarekPiszczaniuk Its can't compile (Before the contents of the structure) `error: array size missing in ‘st’
  struct student st[];` See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/K9OWO8)

Comment: @MarekPiszczaniuk actually Vlad from Moscow's answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

struct student st[1];
char *name = "Marek";
char *surname = "Piszczaniuk";

st[0].name = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
strcpy( st[0].name, name );

st[0].surname = malloc( strlen( surname ) + 1 );
strcpy( st[0].surname, surname );

st[0].score = 100;
```

You can write separate functions to set the data members name and surname for an element of the array.

For example

```
_Bool set_name( struct student *st, const char *name )
{
    st->name = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
    _Bool  success = st->name != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        strcpy( st->name, name );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: Can I try this example to initialise struct with malloc? I know that this quick example, but I'm gradually understand it .

Comment: @MarekPiszczaniuk Yes you can.But it would be correctly said to initialize a data member of the structure with a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an `initialise_student(struct student* s)` function which calls `malloc` on the `char*` members. Perhaps this function also takes the `name` and `surname` `char* pointers` of which you take deep copies?

You then call this function with every member of the `st` array.

Don't forget to build a corresponding `free_student(struct student* s)` function.

Comment: This is not an answer. All you said is: "Use malloc inside a function"

Comment: @TonyTannous: We'll agree to disagree (respectfully, naturally). This answer is pretty much how the early C++ compilers worked.

Comment: @Bathsheba `free_student(struct student* s)` must start after loop with display full result, or maybe must be in display loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using `scanf`, you can tell the function to allocate the sting for you by using `%ms` instead of `%s`, like this:

```
char *name;
if (scanf("%ms", &name) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: could not read name\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

**EDIT** This may not be a valid solution—I forgot that `%ms` is in POSIX only, not in ISO C.

Comment: This is not a part of Standard C, but a POSIX extension.